# 2Checkout API - Does recurring payments have a recurring id associated with it?

Tags: api, recurring, 2checkout

We usually make a 'sale/detail_sale' API call to 2Checkouts URL, to get the details for a particular transaction/sale.

Suppose that the sale is of recurring type.
Will that particular transaction/sale have a recurring_id (or subscription_id) associated with it.

Like in PayPal:
If the transaction is of recurring type, then it has a subscription_id(like I-XXXXXXXXXX) associated with it.
All the transactions related to that subscription will have the same subscription_id, but their transaction_id's are different.The subscription_id acts like the parent-id.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2Checkout recurring sales do not have any additional recurring identifier. All 2Checkout sales have a sale_id, and invoice_id and at least one lineitem_id. Recurring sales create a new invoice on each recurring installment so the [sales/detail_sale](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/api/sales-detail_sale/) API call may return multiple invoices. So the sale_id can have many invoice_id's and each invoice_id can have many linitems_id's.

If you need to stop the recurring billing on a sale, you need to stop the recurring billing an each active recurring lineitem. The lineitem_id is changed on each new invoice on a recurring sale so when making the [stop_lineitem_recurring](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/api/sales-stop_lineitem_recurring/) call it is necessary to use the lineitem_ids from the most recently billed invoice as demonstrated in the [2checkout-php-library](https://github.com/craigchristenson/2checkout-php).

Comment: Can you post me an example/response of detail_sale API call, where the transaction/sale consists of multiple items(like add-to-cart payments). So making the detail_sale to that sale_id will return me a response with details of multiple items.

Comment: Hi Craig, Can you tell me the difference between 'usd_total' and 'usd_amount' in 2Checkout API call (detail_sale)? Also in the documentation it is given as 'total_usd' amount_usd'.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'll make sure it gets updated. `usd_total` is returned at the invoice level so it is the invoice USD total. `usd_amount` is returned at the lineitem level so it is the lineitem USD amount.

Comment: Yes Craig, the documentation needs to be updated. There are other things too that needs to be updated. Thank you.

Comment: So the best way is to use different linkitem_Id for each new customer subscription to track subscription id right?